# Get checkbox values and create window.location URL with them as search parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, serialization

The code is supposed to be a youtube-like website where users can select a bunch of hashtags (via checkboxes) within a form and then click "search" and it's supposed to make a URL dynamically so that "window.location=dynamicURL" will be something like window.location="http://www.example.com/search.php?input1+input3+input4".

I've tried 
    var data = $('form').serialize();
to get started however when I type "data" in console, it says the variable isn't in use.

What I'm looking at doing is using some js to re-serialize the form each time a user clicks on a hashtag checkbox, so that each time a hashtag is clicked, a new array is made (clearing the old array) to be put to use in creating the URL.

I've tried several types of form serialize code and it doesn't seem to fill a variable that the console can see.

examples:

```
function ser()
    {
        $data = 'asd';
        var data = 'add';
        var serial = $("#divid").html($('#formid').serialize());
    }
```

and

```
$('#button1').click(function () {
$("#divid").html($("#formid").find("select,textarea, input").serialize());});
```

both do naught. The var serial is not defined and button1.click doesn't input any html into #divid.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="divid">
<form action="" name="formid" id="formid" onsubmit="return false">
    <button id="button1" onclick="$('.VideoTagsArraysUniqueId').prop('checked', !($('.VideoTagsArraysUniqueId').is(':checked')));ser();">
        <label for="VideoTagsArraysUniqueId" class="VideoTagsArraysUniqueId_label">
            <p>#VideoHashTag</p>
            <input type="checkbox" class="VideoTagsArraysUniqueId" value="VideoHashTag"></input>
            <span class="Checkmark">
        </label>
    </button>
    <button id="button2" onclick="$('.VideoTagsArraysUniqueId').prop('checked', !($('.VideoTagsArraysUniqueId').is(':checked')));ser();">
        <label for="VideoTagsArraysUniqueId" class="VideoTagsArraysUniqueId_label">
            <p>#VideoHashTag</p>
            <input type="checkbox" class="VideoTagsArraysUniqueId" value="VideoHashTag"></input>
            <span class="Checkmark">
        </label>
    </button>
</form>
</div>
```

What I need to do is (when a user clicks on "search"), Get the values and build a js redirect using "window.location=URL" so that the values are separated by "+" so input2+input3+input4.

1. Are the form.serialize() vars I'm trying to declare supposed to output something when typed into the console?
2. Do I need to use ajax and a php script to build this redirecting button?
3. In my code, under "function ser()" I have "$data = 'asd';" and "var data = 'add';". I'm wondering why $data is populating however "data" is not. Are "$variables" treated differently than "variables"?
4. How to get the inputs and make the URL?

Thanks.

Comment: Forms can be submitted as GET method and do it all for you. Just add the `action` url to the form

Comment: I have the action as `www.example.com/search.php?=` but a) it submits and refreshes as soon as I check a checkbox and b) doesn't fill in the URL so that it looks like: `search.php?input1+input2+input3`.

Comment: That's not a proper url without protocol. Or make it a root relative url without host in it

Comment: My URL works with the php I've written in this format: `index.php?Search=input1+input2+input3`

Comment: It was simpler to do an html and php vars version etc.